# Flutter configuration problems

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, repository

I'm trying to start learning Flutter but I've been struggling to run flutter on my android studio since yesterday.

my emulator is greyed out and when I hover on it I get the **"Not applicable in the main.dart configuration"**

on my command prompt, I ran **flutter doctor -v** and I got the following error which I have been unable to fix-

> Flutter (Channel unknown, 0.0.0-unknown, on Microsoft Windows [Version
> 10.0.22000.318], locale en-NG)
> ! Flutter version 0.0.0-unknown on channel unknown at C:\src\flutter
> ! Upstream repository unknown

in my android studio, i'm also getting the

> current configured flutter sdk is not known to be fully supported.
> Please update your SDK and restart intellij.

It's becoming frustrating trying to fix the problems and i'm now considering just switching my interest to React Native if it won't present the same configurations headache i'm currently facing.

Comment: download latest version of flutter and set flutter plugin path to that sdk.

Comment: I literally downloaded the latest version on the flutter website